# Why certain faces dont show texture?

Tags: mesh, texturing, uv, faces

I made some faces with F and those faces dot display texture. What could it be ? thank you in advance for your help...

[image]

Comment: maybe share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=6784" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/6784/)

Comment: @moonboots here it is pal :)

Comment: I figure it out but now the image texture only appears on texture mode, on the render mode its all grey @moonboots

Comment: I don't know Blender Render but it looks like you haven't given any material to your object, other than that the face looks normal so it should work once you'll have set your nodes (in Cycles it would be Image Texture plugged into a Diffuse plugged into the Output)

Comment: Dont worry the render is not important, but still weird how is behaving, thank your for your time man or woman!!! @moonboots

Comment: it's not weird as you haven't affected any material to your object, or as I said maybe I miss something as I'm not familiar with Blender Render. By the way you should switch to Cycles Render because Blender Render won't be used in next Blender versions.

Comment: Select everything in the UV editor and select the texture again.